# Remove row from RecyclerView and database on long click

Tags: java, android

So on long click I'm trying to remove a row in RecyclerView. This is suposed to be easier then in ListView, but somehow I find it harder.

Here's my code:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Todo item = listData.get(position);


        holder.container.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                removeData(item);
                return true;
            }
        });



    }

    private void removeData(Todo infoData) {
        int currentPosition = dbTodo.indexOf(infoData);
        dbTodo.remove(currentPosition);
        notifyItemRemoved(currentPosition);
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think this way seems ok. But can you give me holder's code. And another way i can give you GestureDetector code to handle gesture in RecyclerView